# How to determine whether jQuery UI slider thumb is changed programmatically or by user?

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I am using jQuery UI Slider. I need to know whether the slider change event is a result of user action or programmatically changed.

At http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-option , it was recommended to use the property
event.orginalEvent to detect whether the value changed by mouse, keyboard, or programmatically. But I am always getting this value as "undefined". I am using it as mentioned in the link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slider-event-originalevent

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the type of the event with the following code:

```
$(document).ready((function() {
            $("#slider").slider(
            {
                slide: function(e) {
                    alert(e.originalEvent.type);
                }
            });
        }));
```

as a result "mousemove" alert popped up on every slide.

Check carefully the case, JavaScript is case-sensitive language and if you have tried to access originalEvent but with capital letter it would return undefined.

Comment: I hooked the callback to change event. After changing it to slide event, it worked. Thanks for help.

Comment: @superjoe30 The language you are using is the biggest *lame* thing here. And your hair-trigger down voting.

Comment: what are you talking about? I don't even remember my comment. am I being censored?

Answer (score 0):

It is "**event.originalEvent**" not "*event.orginalEvent*". (**i** is missed !).

Use `e.originalEvent.type` (like Genady said) to find out the event origin.